# C# WPF change grid visibility if combobox item is selected

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to display a `Grid`and its contents when an item (anyone) in `combobox` is selected. If nothing is selected, grid will remain hidden.

**XAML**

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="cb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" Height="25"/>
    <Grid x:Name="gr" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="600"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="346">
                <Border  BorderThickness="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            </Border>
    </Grid>
```

I've tried with this:

**XAML.CS**

```
public void ChangeVisibility(ComboBox cb, Grid gr)
    {
        if (cb.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            gr.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            gr.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
```

But it doesn't change anything. I've tried in multiple ways, even with `string.IsNullOrEmpty`.
Source of `combobox` is a `List<string>`.

**EDIT**

Method is called here

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            ChangeVisibility(cb, gr);
        }
```

Comment: Where/how does `ChangeVisibility` ever get called?

Comment: See the edit, I've added it

Comment: You need an event handler for the SelectionChanged event on the ComboBox. That is where the code in your ChangeVisibility method belongs. Alternatively, you could bind the visibility property to the SelectedItem property in XAML, and use an IValueConverter to check for null.

Comment: If I use the SelectionChanged event, will it be called with every item in the combobox? My grid should be hidden with no selection and visible with any selection

Comment: @Koosshh56 Every time the selection changes in the ComboBox, the event will fire. So if any item gets selected, the grid will show up. If the selected item becomes null (no selection), the grid will become hidden again.

Comment: @MaxHampton exactly what I had in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" Height="25"/>
    <Grid x:Name="gr">
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="600"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="346">
            <Border  BorderThickness="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void ComboBox_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = Combo.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    if (item.Content.ToString() == "Visible")
    {
        RedGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else

    {
        RedGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Name="Combo" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Selected">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Visible" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Hidden" />
    </ComboBox>
    <Grid Name="RedGrid" Grid.Row="1" Background="Red">

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Or to be more similar to your problem:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
private void ComboBox_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = Combo.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        RedGrid.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<ComboBox Name="Combo" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_Selected" >
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Element 1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Element 2" />
</ComboBox>
<Grid Name="RedGrid" Grid.Row="1" Background="Red" Visibility="Hidden">

</Grid>
```

But I am not sure, that your approach is correct. You cannot easily deselect item in ComboBox so basically if you select anything Grid will be always visible. I will rather chose solution with multiple ComboBoxItem where one of them will be "none", "hide" or sth like that.

You can always think about MVVM pattern which is very popular with WPF framework